# Do I have to backup ~/.cashu/wallet/wallet.sqlite3 of my nutshell wallet in order to backup my ecash tokens?

Tags: wallet, backup, custody, cashu

Upon inspection with sqlite, `wallet.sqlite3` has following tables: `balance    dbversions keysets proofs seed balance_used invoices nostr proofs_used`.
As a wallet holder, do I need to back up the file or is the mnemonic phrase enough for backing up my ecash tokens in [nutshell](https://github.com/cashubtc/nutshell)?
If just restoring from the mnemonic is enough, does it also apply when the user has ecash in many CASHU mints?

P.S. The question pertains to ecash, [CASHU protocol](https://docs.cashu.space), and to Chaumian mints and not to
any scamcoins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimentation that included deleting `.cashu/` I can confirm that I am able to restore the funds [just from the mnemonic phrase](https://github.com/cashubtc/nutshell/pull/131).